# Xcode:Autolayout set a view to always be in top

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, uiinterfaceorientation, autolayout

I'm trying to set a view to always be in top be so far I have not figure out how to do it.
In this case it shows correctly:

[image]

But in this case it doesn't:

[image]

How do I need to set up my view with auto layout in way the view always shows in top?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Here is how I setup the view in interface builder:

[image]

Comment: and is your app is universal??? ... because in landscape mode your status bar is at the right side not  on top ....

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Yes is universal and the project is set for portrait, landscape left/right.

Comment: @user2924482 some time it happen that orientation not change in simulator, so pls check it in real device....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the screenshots, works well for me.[image: The constraints]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Landscape image you shared, status bar is in not changed as per orientation.Make sure you have enabled Landscape-Left and Landscape-Right. Check following image. [image]

Comment: as I mention and my previous comment. I have set my project that way.

Comment: The issue is related to orientation. Not related to auto layout. Check for code which is restricting the orientation change for that view controller or it's parent or navigation controller.

Comment: my problem as I mention in post. My goal is for the view always be in top.